# Undesirable empty spaces between rows while using longtable

Tags: spacing, longtable, white-space

I am using longtable which consist of 4 columns & 7 rows of reasonably consist of long sentences. The problem is that when one row was typeset it leaves more space on that page & prints the next row on the next page.

[image: Longtable pic]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}%

%%%%%%%%%%%Packages Initialization%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mylipsum}{The Hadean eon represents the time before a reliable (fossil) record of life; it began with the formation of the planet and ended 4.0 billion years ago.}
\newcommand{\Mylipsum}{\mylipsum{} \mylipsum}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{p{0.15\textwidth}p{0.22\textwidth}p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.28\textwidth}}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Test long table} \label{tab:testlongtable}\\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{p{0.15\textwidth}}{\centering \textbf{Column1}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.22\textwidth}}{\centering \textbf{Column2}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.25\textwidth}}{\centering \textbf{Column3}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.28\textwidth}}{\centering \textbf{Column4}}\\ \hline 
\endfirsthead
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption[]{Test long table} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{p{0.15\textwidth}}{\centering \textbf{Column1}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.22\textwidth}}{\centering \textbf{Column2}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.25\textwidth}}{\centering \textbf{Column3}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.28\textwidth}}{\centering \textbf{Column4}}\\ \hline 
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{Continued on next page..} \\ 
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
\mylipsum &The following Archean and Proterozoic eons produced the beginnings of life on Earth and its earliest evolution. The succeeding eon is the Phanerozoic, divided into three eras: the Palaeozoic, an era of arthropods, fishes, and the first life on land; the Mesozoic, which spanned the rise, reign, and climactic extinction of the non-avian dinosaurs; and the Cenozoic, which saw the rise of mammals. Recognizable humans emerged at most 2 million years ago, a vanishingly small period on the geological scale.&The following Archean and Proterozoic eons produced the beginnings of life on Earth and its earliest evolution. The succeeding eon is the Phanerozoic, divided into three eras: the Palaeozoic, an era of arthropods, fishes, and the first life on land; the Mesozoic, which spanned the rise, reign, and climactic extinction of the non-avian dinosaurs; and the Cenozoic, which saw the rise of mammals. Recognizable humans emerged at most 2 million years ago, a vanishingly small period on the geological scale.&\mylipsum\\
\midrule
\mylipsum &The following Archean and Proterozoic eons produced the beginnings of life on Earth and its earliest evolution. The succeeding eon is the Phanerozoic, divided into three eras: the Palaeozoic, an era of arthropods, fishes, and the first life on land; the Mesozoic, which spanned the rise, reign, and climactic extinction of the non-avian dinosaurs; and the Cenozoic, which saw the rise of mammals. Recognizable humans emerged at most 2 million years ago, a vanishingly small period on the geological scale.&The following Archean and Proterozoic eons produced the beginnings of life on Earth and its earliest evolution. The succeeding eon is the Phanerozoic, divided into three eras: the Palaeozoic, an era of arthropods, fishes, and the first life on land; the Mesozoic, which spanned the rise, reign, and climactic extinction of the non-avian dinosaurs; and the Cenozoic, which saw the rise of mammals. Recognizable humans emerged at most 2 million years ago, a vanishingly small period on the geological scale.&\mylipsum\\
\midrule
\mylipsum &The following Archean and Proterozoic eons produced the beginnings of life on Earth and its earliest evolution. The succeeding eon is the Phanerozoic, divided into three eras: the Palaeozoic, an era of arthropods, fishes, and the first life on land; the Mesozoic, which spanned the rise, reign, and climactic extinction of the non-avian dinosaurs; and the Cenozoic, which saw the rise of mammals. Recognizable humans emerged at most 2 million years ago, a vanishingly small period on the geological scale.&The following Archean and Proterozoic eons produced the beginnings of life on Earth and its earliest evolution. The succeeding eon is the Phanerozoic, divided into three eras: the Palaeozoic, an era of arthropods, fishes, and the first life on land; the Mesozoic, which spanned the rise, reign, and climactic extinction of the non-avian dinosaurs; and the Cenozoic, which saw the rise of mammals. Recognizable humans emerged at most 2 million years ago, a vanishingly small period on the geological scale.&\mylipsum\\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Pagebreaks when using `longtable` can only occur between rows not within rows.

Comment: To prevent large white spaces, you could try to rotate the table to a landscape orientation, and adjust the column widths so the texts in the individual columns take approximately the same height. With this, you might be able to fit two rows onto a singla page.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but please remove the `center` environment around the `longtable` as `longtables` are by default horizontally centered on the page.For the column headers, I'd also recomment the use of the `\thead` command from  the `makecell` package.

Comment: @leandriis. Thank you. is any other way to solve the problem in portrait orientation by using other packages like a table or tabular. However, I will use landscape orientation as it seems feasible.

Comment: `table` and `tabular` can not spread over multiple pages, so they are not suitable if your table is longer than one page.

Comment: I will remove the center comment.

Comment: If you adjust the column widths in order to reduce the amount of white space, the first nd last column would get extremely narrow. Therefore I suggested rotating the table.

Comment: @leandriis, Thank you once again for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rotating the table to a landscape orientation and adjusting the column widths accordingly, you can minimize the vertical and horizontal white space in your table. Depending on the actual contents, 2 rows of the table might fit onto a single page. As already recommended in the comments, I have also used the `\thead` command from the `makecell` package for the column headers and also replaced the `\hline` commands with the rules from the `booktabs` package that you already load.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}%

%%%%%%%%%%%Packages Initialization%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{calc}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mylipsum}{The Hadean eon represents the time before a reliable (fossil) record of life; it began with the formation of the planet and ended 4.0 billion years ago.}
\newcommand{\Mylipsum}{\mylipsum{} \mylipsum}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.125\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
                  p{0.325\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
                  p{0.325\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
                  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.125\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Test long table} \label{tab:testlongtable}\\
\toprule
\thead{Column1} & \thead{Column2} & \thead{Column3} & \thead{Column4}\\ \midrule 
\endfirsthead
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption[]{Test long table} \\
\toprule
\thead{Column1} & \thead{Column2} & \thead{Column3} & \thead{Column4}\\ \midrule 
\endhead
\multicolumn{4}{r}{Continued on next page..} \\ 
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\mylipsum &The following Archean and Proterozoic eons produced the beginnings of life on Earth and its earliest evolution. The succeeding eon is the Phanerozoic, divided into three eras: the Palaeozoic, an era of arthropods, fishes, and the first life on land; the Mesozoic, which spanned the rise, reign, and climactic extinction of the non-avian dinosaurs; and the Cenozoic, which saw the rise of mammals. Recognizable humans emerged at most 2 million years ago, a vanishingly small period on the geological scale.&The following Archean and Proterozoic eons produced the beginnings of life on Earth and its earliest evolution. The succeeding eon is the Phanerozoic, divided into three eras: the Palaeozoic, an era of arthropods, fishes, and the first life on land; the Mesozoic, which spanned the rise, reign, and climactic extinction of the non-avian dinosaurs; and the Cenozoic, which saw the rise of mammals. Recognizable humans emerged at most 2 million years ago, a vanishingly small period on the geological scale.&\mylipsum\\
\midrule
\mylipsum &The following Archean and Proterozoic eons produced the beginnings of life on Earth and its earliest evolution. The succeeding eon is the Phanerozoic, divided into three eras: the Palaeozoic, an era of arthropods, fishes, and the first life on land; the Mesozoic, which spanned the rise, reign, and climactic extinction of the non-avian dinosaurs; and the Cenozoic, which saw the rise of mammals. Recognizable humans emerged at most 2 million years ago, a vanishingly small period on the geological scale.&The following Archean and Proterozoic eons produced the beginnings of life on Earth and its earliest evolution. The succeeding eon is the Phanerozoic, divided into three eras: the Palaeozoic, an era of arthropods, fishes, and the first life on land; the Mesozoic, which spanned the rise, reign, and climactic extinction of the non-avian dinosaurs; and the Cenozoic, which saw the rise of mammals. Recognizable humans emerged at most 2 million years ago, a vanishingly small period on the geological scale.&\mylipsum\\
\midrule
\mylipsum &The following Archean and Proterozoic eons produced the beginnings of life on Earth and its earliest evolution. The succeeding eon is the Phanerozoic, divided into three eras: the Palaeozoic, an era of arthropods, fishes, and the first life on land; the Mesozoic, which spanned the rise, reign, and climactic extinction of the non-avian dinosaurs; and the Cenozoic, which saw the rise of mammals. Recognizable humans emerged at most 2 million years ago, a vanishingly small period on the geological scale.&The following Archean and Proterozoic eons produced the beginnings of life on Earth and its earliest evolution. The succeeding eon is the Phanerozoic, divided into three eras: the Palaeozoic, an era of arthropods, fishes, and the first life on land; the Mesozoic, which spanned the rise, reign, and climactic extinction of the non-avian dinosaurs; and the Cenozoic, which saw the rise of mammals. Recognizable humans emerged at most 2 million years ago, a vanishingly small period on the geological scale.&\mylipsum\\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```